# How do you convert from vector equation of a plane to general equation?

Tags: geometry

Is there a way to go from a vector equation for example :
$$
[x, y, z] = [1, 6, 2] + s[3, -2, 5] + t[5, 1, -6] 
$$
to general equation which is the form:
$$
ax+by+cz+d=0\ ?
$$

Comment: Do you know about normal vectors? If so, take the cross product of two (independent) vectors in the plane to get a normal vector to the plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so we are given the two direction vectors.  The equation of a plane is stated based on its normal.  so we take the cross product of the two direction vectors to get a vector perpendicular to both.

\begin{array}{l}
\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
3\\
{ - 2}\\
5
\end{array}} \right] \times \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
5\\
1\\
{ - 6}
\end{array}} \right]\\
 = \left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1\\
0\\
0
\end{array}} \right]}&{\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0\\
1\\
0
\end{array}} \right]}&{\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0\\
0\\
1
\end{array}} \right]}\\
3&{ - 2}&5\\
5&1&{ - 6}
\end{array}} \right|\\
 = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1\\
0\\
0
\end{array}} \right]\;\cdot\left( { - 2\;\cdot\;\left( { - 6} \right) - 1\;\cdot\;5} \right) - \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0\\
1\\
0
\end{array}} \right]\;\cdot\left( { - 6\;\cdot\;3 - 5\;\cdot\;5} \right)\; + \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0\\
0\\
1
\end{array}} \right]\;\cdot\;\left( {1\;\cdot\;3 - 5\;\cdot\;\left( { - 2} \right)} \right)\\
 = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
7\\
{43}\\
{13}
\end{array}} \right]
\end{array}

now that we have the normal [a,b,c] we can create the scalar equation for a plane from it:  Ax+By+Xz+D=0

Now we know A,B,and C.  We don't know D, but we can sub in the given point [1,6,2] to find D.

\begin{array}{l}
7x + 43y + 13z + D = 0\\
7\;\cdot\;\left( 1 \right) + 43\;\cdot\;\left( 6 \right) + 13\;\cdot\;\left( 2 \right)\; + D = 0\\
D =  - 291\\
\\
so:\\
7x + 43y + 13z - 291 = 0
\end{array}